# Web forwarding proxy in C# or PHP available?

Tags: c#, php, proxy, http-headers, forwarding

I have some shared server web hosting in the States (I'm from the UK), which allows me to publish PHP and .NET applications. I cannot install my own software onto the remote server, but I'd like to set up a web forwarding proxy for accessing sites that serve different content depending on what country you're from.

My C# and ASP.NET skills are OK, but my PHP is very limited. Are there any solutions that anyone would recommend for this sort of problem? The proxies I've investigated all seem to require installation on the server machine itself, whereas I'm just looking for something that's accessible from a URL.

Obviously, as the requests are coming from the UK, the headers will have to be manipulated by the proxy before forwarding them on. I was going to code my own HTTP handler in C#, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's something out there already ;)

Comment: Your question is fuzzy. Are you supposed to forward to a url based on the country of the client, or is that something handled by the destination and irrelevant for the question?

Answer (score 1):

Although quite old, the Org.Mentalis.Proxy could be a good starting point for an example proxy implementation in C#. You can find it here: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Sergiu. Unfortunately, it appears that the Mentalis Proxy is geared towards installation on a server, but I'm sure the C# code will be a great reference if I write my own implementation.

Comment: You're welcome. Generally speaking, a HTTP proxy is a server. Of course it can be used on a normal machine, can be used for debugging HTTP headers or intercepting & analyzing traffic (there are specialized tools for this purpose). It's very well written anyway, so it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this script is helping you? [phproxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/)

Comment: Thank you for the link drfuture. It's a shame that phproxy is not being developed any more, but I'll certainly give the script a try.